# Oracle Apex SQL throwing error for correct syntax in SELECT * FROM commands?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-apex

Input:

```
SELECT * FROM ANIMAL;
SELECT * FROM DRUG;
SELECT * FROM TREATMENT;
SELECT * FROM DRUGUSAGE;
```

Error that is being shown:

> ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended

When I do just one `SELECT * FROM` line, each and every table prints in the output just fine. So why when I put them together does this error pop-up?

I can't figure it out for the life of me. Thank you!

Comment: Try to remove the `;`

Comment: tried that. same error :/ @SelVazi

Comment: This is the behaviour of the APEX SQL Workshop. You can have multiple present, and highlight one SQL at a time for execution, or you can define them as a stored script and execute them that way.

Answer (score 0):

Oracle only accepts one SQL statement per command (this helps to prevent some SQL injection attacks). Some other RDBMS will accept multiple SQL statements within a command.

Some IDEs allow you to run scripts and the IDE will start a transaction (although this is done implicitly by Oracle) and split your script up into individual commands and run each command within the transaction.

APEX SQL Workbench just runs single commands; therefore each command you run **MUST** be a single SQL statement.

Alternatively, as [commented by @Scott](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76223014/oracle-apex-sql-throwing-error-for-correct-syntax-in-select-from-commands#comment134418316_76223014):

> you can define them as a stored script and execute them that way.